# Is it possible to change the code and see the results right away on Android?

Tags: android, compilation, android-gradle-plugin

Often I'm making some small changes, within one file, not touching 99% of the code. For example: small refactoring, tweaking parameters, layouts, animations. Changes which take couple of seconds. I just want to quickly experiment with many options and see what is the best.

There is a huge problem - recompilation and deploying time. I waste my time and lose my focus, which dramatically increases total tweaking time - from seconds of actual work to minutes (hours?), because of waiting and constant distractions. It's also annoying and doesn't encourage to experiment more.

I've heard about [DyCI](http://dyci.github.io/) - Dynamic Code Injection, which does exactly what I want - "change your code and see the results right away". But, it's for iOS.

**Is it possible to change the code and see the results right away on Android? How?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use incremental dex-ing

> Full Incremental Builds – The new Gradle-based Android build system
>   has been designed for developer efficiency. Gradle’s support for
>   incremental tasks means you spend less time waiting and more time
>   coding.

from https://www.gradleware.com/android/gradle-the-new-android-build-system/

Also
[What does the "Incremental Dex" option in Android Studio do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779552/what-does-the-incremental-dex-option-in-android-studio-do)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about hotswap, I think it's not possible with Dalvik VM (android's java virtual machine). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11742814/4576054) answer tells it too